# How to select row by latest product transaction with correct value of another value in row

Tags: mysql

Hi I have table(transaction_detail) that contain 2 foreign key from product and transaction,
how can I select the latest product with correct transaction_id ?

in transaction table there's (id, transaction_date, total_price, tax, etc) and
in transaction_detail there's (id, transaction_id, product_id, price, qty, etc)

here is the example data of transaction table

| id | transaction_date | total_price | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6ab7119c-0637-4e46-b640-e3ee400888cc | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 | 50 | 0 |
| b18a3a5d-3ce2-441e-98b5-ce8e1525ea4c | 2020-01-01 15:00:00 | 60 | 0 |
| 48bbd11b-2163-4a74-ade0-52cdf4a20aa7 | 2020-01-01 13:30:00 | 40 | 0 |

and here is the example data of transaction_detail

| id | transaction_id | product_id | price | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62e6b6d6-a52d-40ca-bb8d-8569d3582d03 | 6ab7119c-0637-4e46-b640-e3ee400888cc | 1 | 5 | 10 |
| c38cffd2-b788-4a26-acc6-d096aa014249 | 6ab7119c-0637-4e46-b640-e3ee400888cc | 2 | 3 | 20 |
| b651a298-3d8b-410a-af68-8874eeb26707 | 48bbd11b-2163-4a74-ade0-52cdf4a20aa7 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 5982867d-66c0-4d63-8e2b-0b155d3d851a | 48bbd11b-2163-4a74-ade0-52cdf4a20aa7 | 3 | 6 | 2 |

the result that I want

| transaction_id | product_id | transaction_date | price | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6ab7119c-0637-4e46-b640-e3ee400888cc | 1 | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 | 5 | 10 |
| 6ab7119c-0637-4e46-b640-e3ee400888cc | 2 | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 | 3 | 20 |
| 48bbd11b-2163-4a74-ade0-52cdf4a20aa7 | 3 | 2020-01-01 13:30:00 | 6 | 2 |

here is all of the query that I use but the result is not correct,

1.

```
SELECT transaction_id, product_id, max(transaction_date) as transaction_date, price, qty
from transaction_detail GROUP BY product_id
```

the problems of this query is select the lates of the transaction date, not the transaction_id

the another way I use this query

```
SELECT transaction_id, product_id, transaction_date, price, qty
from transaction_detail
     join transaction on transaction.id = transaction_id from transaction_detail
WHERE transaction_date IN (
  SELECT max(transaction_date) as transaction_date
  from transaction_detail
) GROUP BY product_id
```

This's sometimes can give me the correct result, but now when the transaction_date has same value, it give incorrect result

how can I correcty select the latest product transaction, with correct transaction_id, price, qty and with group by product_id ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
select 
transaction_id,
product_id,
(select transaction_date from transaction where id=transaction_detail.transaction_id) as transaction_date,
price,
qty
from transaction_detail
```